# LinkedIn API in Python: How to get code while running it on command line

Tags: python, python-3.x, linkedin-api

I am writing a command line script accessing LinkedIN API via Library but having issues with it. Here is my code:

```
from linkedin import linkedin
import requests
RETURN_URL = "http://localhost"
authentication = linkedin.LinkedInAuthentication(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, RETURN_URL,
                                                 linkedin.PERMISSIONS.enums.values())
print(authentication.authorization_url)
get_code = authentication.authorization_url
application = linkedin.LinkedInApplication(authentication)
authentication.authorization_code = 'AQQfHou58eyVEJmbabHk1njdl-AY0bqfDjkZeosAn6DR-DiTnH7raJoDcign2U3w5w1YieYU4cjfTz3Ab-wa7cm3KwwctjzU-SoAWchjj_odArFM7q1W1CCU_15Q7gLDRrZoMCo5ivXnkisR5gYfGS0V2E_jsQ&state=74abc361c20313f5bc87d43f42f88b53#!'
# authentication.get_access_token()

data = {
    'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
    'client_secret': CLIENT_SECRET,
    'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
    'redirect_uri': RETURN_URL,
    'code': 'AQTqmP0g4PWGJpNnSysqvH4TCXTusoWsjbx1f3R7TPazYP4pCB81a4FrRJRUNjeJzH5yoN2XTrIT4YO-mu2VBQkhL12kwJZ09Xm_WHh97nyok0tqKHh8k54c3dCc075hrsJ8KYw02X-2XSMD-TkxQWKrUXPsMw&state=82d8d2bbbc80ba485812d2fe500cf3e9#!'
}

url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken'
r = requests.post(url, data=data)
print(r.text)
```

The error I get:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?client_id=862ztaa9740mst&redirect_uri=http%3A//localhost&scope=rw_company_admin%20r_emailaddress%20r_basicprofile%20w_share&response_type=code&state=d8e7aaefdbd32211fb7d342b238a84dc
{"error_description":"missing required parameters, includes an invalid parameter value, parameter more than once. : Unable to retrieve access token : appId or redirect uri does not match authorization code or authorization code expired","error":"invalid_request"}
```

Also, how to get `code` part dynamically?

Comment: The error message gives you a couple of possible reasons: "appId or redirect uri does not match authorization code or authorization code expired."

Comment: @DYZ the way I want to implement that script will run as cron and I don't know how will I get access token. not sure how`appid` is given but redirect_url does match